# How to put the list horizontally starting next to a different elem (input elem for example)

Tags: html, css

I was trying to "clone code" a GitHub website, and I am stuck on how to put the list horizontally. [(as seen here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWyJY.png)

Here is my CSS code :

```css
#section1{
  background-color: black;
  height: 7%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

#logo1{
  position: relative;
  left: 2%;
  top: 13px;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

#searchBar{
  height: 20px; 
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(180,180,180);
  padding: 7px;
}

input[id^="searchBar"]::placeholder {
  color: rgb(220,220,220)
}
```

And here is my HTML code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <Title></Title>
      <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "clone1.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <section id = "section1">
         <a href = "https://github.com/">
            <img id = "logo1" src = "img/logo1.png">
         </a>
         <input id = "searchBar" type = "text" placeholder="search or jump to...">
         <span>Pull</span>
            <ul>
               <li>Pull requests</li>
            </ul>
      </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

I was expecting the list starting next to the search bar because the section1 has the CSS code "float: left".
Could anyone tell me how I can layout the list horizontally starting next to the search bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added:

```
#section1 > * { display:inline-block; }
```

Feel free to adjust the CSS to align more closely with your requirements. Chose `inline-block` as dimensional styling will take effect (like `padding` and `margin`).

NB: This is, apparently, "[legacy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Legacy)".

```css
#section1{
    background-color: black;
    height: 7%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

#logo1{
    position: relative;
    left: 2%;
    top: 13px;
    margin-right: 60px;
}

#searchBar{
    height: 20px; 
    width: 250px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(180,180,180);
    padding: 7px;
}

input[id^="searchBar"]::placeholder {
    color: rgb(220,220,220)
}
#section1 > * { display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <Title></Title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "clone1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id = "section1">
            <a href = "https://github.com/">
                <img id = "logo1" src = "img/logo1.png">
            </a>
            <input id = "searchBar" type = "text" placeholder="search or jump to...">
            <span>Pull</span>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Pull requests
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To clarify what's happening, `ul` is what's known as a `block` element, which means that it starts on a new line by default. By changing  all of the immediate children of `section1` to `display:inline-block`, this allows the respective elements to not be placed on a new line, rather on the same line after one another.